# React Native Mapbox RNMBXModels.models.getter not implemented (Expo Project)

Tags: react-native, three.js, expo, mapbox, gltf

I'm trying to use 3D models in Mapbox, and for that I'm using the new ModelLayer component

I installed the packages and ran the `npx expo prebuild` command to generate the native code

I installed the App on my iOS phone using the `expo run:ios --device` command

The app loads and the map renders normally, but I get the following error

`Mapbox [error] RNMBXModels.models.getter not implemented`

I also tried using the Expo Asset to load the model and replace the require in the Models component with the asset uri or localUri, but I got the same error

I tried with 2 different model extensions: GLB and GLTF, which are attached below:

[models.zip](https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/files/14456143/models.zip)

Mapbox Version: 11.1.0

React Native Version: 0.73.4

Platform: iOS

@rnmapbox/maps Version: 10.1.17

#### Component to reproduce

metro.config.js:

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
config.resolver.assetExts.push("gltf", "glb");
module.exports = config;
```

app.json:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "my-app",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@rnmapbox/maps",
        {
          "RNMapboxMapsVersion": "11.1.0",
          "RNMapboxMapsDownloadToken": "token..."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@rnmapbox/maps": "^10.1.17",
    "expo": "~50.0.6",
    "expo-asset": "~9.0.2",
    "expo-gl": "^13.6.0",
    "expo-three": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "three": "^0.162.0"
  }
}
```

src/screens/explore/Main/Main.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import MapboxGL from "@rnmapbox/maps";

const MainContainer = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MapboxGL.MapView
        projection="globe"
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        logoEnabled={false}
        compassEnabled
        compassFadeWhenNorth
        scaleBarEnabled={false}
        pitchEnabled
      >
        <MapboxGL.Models models={{ car: require("./model.glb") }} />
        <MapboxGL.Camera zoomLevel={1} animationDuration={1.5} />
        <MapboxGL.ShapeSource key={chunk.id} shape={chunk} id={chunk.id}>
          <MapboxGL.ModelLayer
            id={`example-id`}
            style={{
              modelId: "car",
            }}
          />
        </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
      </MapboxGL.MapView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default MainContainer;
```

Using the `<MapboxGL.Images images={{ example: require("./image.png") }}  />` with a SymbolLayer works and I can see the images on the map.

Using `@react-three/fiber/native` and `@react-three/drei/native` to render the model on the screen works normally, I used the following code for this:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { useFrame, Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber/native";
import { useGLTF, Environment } from "@react-three/drei/native";
import modelPath from "./model.glb";

function Model({ url, ...rest }) {
  const { scene } = useGLTF(url);
  useFrame(() => (scene.rotation.y += 0.01));
  return <primitive {...rest} object={scene} />;
}

const MainContainer = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
      <Canvas gl={{ physicallyCorrectLights: true }} camera={{ position: [-6, 0, 16], fov: 36 }}>
        <color attach="background" args={[0xe2f4df]} />
        <ambientLight />
        <directionalLight intensity={1.1} position={[0.5, 0, 0.866]} />
        <directionalLight intensity={0.8} position={[-6, 2, 2]} />
        <Suspense>
          <Environment preset="park" />
          <Model url={modelPath} />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    </View>
  );
};
```